# Python - How do I separate data into multiple lines

Tags: python-3.x

I have two strings that i want to put into a txt file but when I try and write then, it's only on the first line, I want the string to be on separate lines how do I do so?

Here is the writing part of my code btw:

```
saveFile = open('points.txt', 'w')
saveFile.write(str(jakesPoints))
saveFile.write(str(alexsPoints))
saveFile.close
```

if jakesPoints was 10 and alexsPoints was 12 then the text file would be

```
1012
```

but i want to to be

```
10
12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a newline character (`\n`) to move to a new line. For your example:

```
with open('points.txt', 'w') as saveFile:
    saveFile.write("{}\n".format(jakesPoints))
    saveFile.write("{}\n".format(alexsPoints))
```

The other things to note:

- It is helpful to open files using `with` - this will take care of opening and closing the file automatically (which is typically preferred over trying to remember to `.close()`).
- The `{}.format()` section is used to convert your numbers to a string and add the newline character. I found https://pyformat.info/ explained the string formatters pretty good and highlight all the main advantages.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('points.txt', 'w') as saveFile:  
         saveFile.write(str(jakesPoints))
         saveFile.write("\n")
         saveFile.write(str(alexsPoints))
```

See difference between`w` and `a` used in `open()`. Also see `join()` .